# How to use SetTimeout to introduce time delay in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, settimeout

I have tried a number of methods and am stumped...

I need to introduce a wait in the following code to prevent frequent page reloading...

```
// Need to Introduce 5 Second wait here
  $$("a[href*='city']")[0].click();
```

As I understand it, this should be possible with SetTimeout, but I haven't been able to get the syntax to work properly.

Thanks,

```js
function checkEnemies(){
 numEnemies = parseInt(document.querySelector("#tb_enemies b").textContent);
 if (numEnemies < 1){
  $$("a[href*='train']")[0].click();
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}

var bool = checkEnemies();

if (!bool){ 
// Need to Introduce 5 Second wait here
  $$("a[href*='city']")[0].click();
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { put code here; }, 5000)`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: It worked! How do i confirm your answer?

Comment: It's not even an answer. This is too basic to bother with.